# Why does sed not replace all occurrences?

Tags: bash, sed

If I run this code in bash:

```
echo dog dog dos | sed -r 's:dog:log:'
```

it gives output:

```
log dog dos
```

How can I make it replace all occurrences of dog?

Comment: You need the `g` flag for global substitution, you don't need the `-r` option here either.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

You should add the `g` modifier so that sed performs a *global* substitution of the contents of the pattern buffer:

```
echo dog dog dos | sed -e 's:dog:log:g'
```

For a fantastic documentation on sed, check http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html. This *global* flag is explained here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-6

The official documentation for `GNU sed` is available at http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/

Comment: Adding a corner case for GNU sed here: `sed -E 's,foo,bar,g'` doesn't do the global thing. If you change it to `sed -E -e 's,foo,bar,g'` it works.

Comment: If you want to replace all on the line AND on the other lines as well it will also work: `echo 'dog dog dos\ndog'|sed 's:dog:log:g`

Comment: The standard manual page for GNU sed is very poor describing `s` and flag `g`, but the (text)info page (sed.info) states for "FLAGS g": "*Apply the replacement to _all_ matches to the REGEXP, not just the first.*".

Answer (score 39):

You have to put a `g` at the end, it stands for "global":

```
echo dog dog dos | sed -r 's:dog:log:g'
                                     ^
```

Comment: sed -e should be used instead of sed -r, which does not exist.

Comment: @DylanDaniels According to `man sed` on Ubuntu, the `-r` option means "use extended regular expressions". So the given command works fine, although it doesn't need the features of extended regular expressions to work.