# Linux Script: substituting a multiple lines with single line of text

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What shell script should I use in Linux to replace a group with n lines of text with a single line?

I have a file like :

```
a
b
c
*
d
e
f
*
g
h
i
*
```

and I want to get a file as:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Comment: Something like 'i=0; while read line; do test $((++i))', but I haven't found any solution

Comment: I just saw your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21042715/1983854 . Why don't you give proper input? All the approaches were based on your input which is very far from the one you are using in your answer.

Comment: @fedorqui and besides, his/her answer is the longest and least understandable of all :)

Answer (score 2):

can use awk

```
awk '{if ($0=="*"){print s;s=""}else{s=s$0}}' file
```

an bash way to this is

```
while read x
do
   [ "$x" == "*" ] && echo  || echo -n $x
done < file
```

Answer (score 2):

sed way:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' < t | sed 's:*:\n:g'
```

t is the file you want to change.

references:
[How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)
[Why does sed not replace all occurrences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849119/why-does-sed-not-replace-all-occurrences)

The first command replaces \n with nothing. the second replaces * with \n.

sed is a very powerful stream editor tool by the way, knowing it can help you in more ways than you can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

**Other than awk solution :**

```
tr '\n' ' ' < Input.txt |sed 's/ //g' | tr '*' '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

One `awk` way:

```
$ awk '/\*/ {printf "\n"; next} {printf $1}' file
abc
def
ghi
```

- In case of `*`, print a new line. Otherwise, print the character. Using `printf`, so that new line is not added unless specified.

---

With `xargs`:

```
$ xargs -n4 < file | cut -d' ' -f1-3
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

- `xargs -n4 < file` prints the file in blocks of 4 columns. `cut -d' ' -f1-3` prints from 1st to 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

If you treat `*` as the line token, try remove '\n' and replace STAR.

```
cat <youfile> | tr -d '\n' | tr '*' '\n'
```

Comment: instead of using 2 pipes, you could have said `tr -d '\n' < file | tr '*' '\n'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the shell without awk, or tr, or anything external too:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read x
do
   if [ "$x" == "*" ]; then
      echo $line
      line=""
   else
      line="$line$x"
   fi
done
```

Save as "go", then do:

```
chmod +x go
./go <inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe tr could be considered the correct tool to replace single characters.

```
tr -d '\n' < file | tr '*' '\n'
```

Correct in this context would mean most lightweight, least clumsy, least bug-prone, and least cognitively demanding for the purpose. The other solutions work, but tr has the least hidden costs. When you use a lot of small tools as you do in unix, these small advantages really add up over time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody, I've found this solution which works in case the file is like

```
field1     2008
field2     703
field3     qeew
field4     80
field5     52
field6     749.11

field1     2009
field2     532
field3     wecwer
field4     82
field5     44
field6     649.97
```

...

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "" ]
then
   echo "missing file name"
   exit 1
fi

N=7
i=0
FULL_ROW=""
SAVEIFS=$IFS
if [ -f $1 -a -r $1 ]; then
    LAST_DATA_SCAD=""
    while IFS=$(echo -en "|\n\b") read -ra ROW_RECORD; do

    if [[ "$FULL_ROW" == "" ]]
       then
        FULL_ROW=${ROW_RECORD:11}
       else
        FULL_ROW=$FULL_ROW"|"${ROW_RECORD:11}
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
    if [ $((10#$i)) == $N ]
    then
      echo $FULL_ROW
      FULL_ROW=""
      i=0
    fi
    done < "$1"
   else
     echo "file not found"
   fi
   IFS=$SAVEIFS
```