# Use sed to find and replace all instances of a pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm not very good with sed. It just looks complicated. However I've mnaged to learn how to replace all instances of a string with another string

```
sed 's/replace-this/with-this/FLAG'
```

However, if I want to say replace all words that start with "a" and have a third letter "p", with fruit, how would I do that?

Comment: I meant to say that I would like to replace all words that start with "a" and have a third letter "p", with the word "fruit".

Comment: Do you have to use `sed` ? or is a pure Bash solution is ok?

Comment: If `sed` is optional and a pure bash solution is acceptable, then you might want to take a look at this: `read -ra arr <<< "$var"; printf -v var '%s' "${arr[*]//a?p*/fruit}";` with `var="apple is a fruit"`, for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does sed not replace all occurrences?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15849119/608639)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\<a\wp\w*\>/fruit/g' file
```

This uses the `\<` opening word boundary as a marker for the start of a word beginning with a the character `a`, followed by another word character, followed by a `p`, followed by zero or more word characters, followed by a `\>` closing word boundary to be replaced by the word `fruit` globally.

Comment: `sed` does not have a uniform sense of [word boundaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382272/beginning-and-end-of-words-in-sed-and-grep) unfortunately. `\<` and `\>` are GNU only

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ echo "$tgt"
app
apple
applesauce
grape
gum
apple is a fruit
text apple and pears
```

You can do:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | sed 's/a.p.*/fruit/'
fruit
fruit
fruit
grape
gum
fruit
text fruit
```

---

If you want the word only (not the remainder of the line) you can do:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | sed -E 's/a.p[a-zA-Z]*/fruit/'
fruit
fruit
fruit
grape
gum
fruit is a fruit
text fruit and pears
```

Comment: What about the line `apple is a fruit`?

Comment: I assume `apple is a fruit` should become `fruit is a fruit`.

Comment: As written, it will replace the remainder of the line after `a.p` so `apple is a fruit` and the rest of the line would become `fruit`

Comment: I'm sorry. I should've have clarified something. I want to replace only the word not the entire line. So as pfnuesel mentioned above, I would like to change the line "apple is a fruit" to "fruit is a fruit" and the line "appetizers etc" with "fruits etc"

Comment: Thanks also for clarifying that `fruit is a fruit` :p

Comment: `sed` does not have a uniform sense of [word boundaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382272/beginning-and-end-of-words-in-sed-and-grep).

Comment: You will be replacing "grasp" with "grfruit".

Comment: @tripleee: Agreed, but how do you do a multi sed version of `\b` or `\<`?

Comment: If portability is a concern, maybe switch to Perl instead. `perl -pe 's/\<a\wp\w*/fruit/g'`